# Integrating a function using non-uniform measure (python/scipy)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, probability, numerical-methods

I would like to integrate a function in python and provide the probability density (measure) used to sample values. If it's not obvious, integrating `f(x)dx` in `[a,b]` implicitly use the uniform probability density over `[a,b]`, and I would like to use my own probability density (e.g. exponential).

I can do it myself, using `np.random.*` but then

- I miss the optimizations available in `scipy.integrate.quad`. Or maybe all those optimizations assume the uniform density?
- I need to do the error estimation myself, which is not trivial. Or maybe it is? Maybe the error is just the variance of `sum(f(x))/n`?

Any ideas?

Comment: Can the integral of `f(x) d(mu)` (where `mu` is the measure) be represented as the integral of `f(x)g(x) dx` for some density function `g`?

Comment: yes, I can assume either that I have g explicitly or that I can sample x according to g. I see where you're headed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As unutbu said, if you have the density function, the you can just integrate the product of your function with the pdf using `scipy.integrate.quad`.

For the distribution that are available in `scipy.stats`, we can also just use the expect function.

For example

```
>>> from scipy import stats

>>> f = lambda x: x**2

>>> stats.norm.expect(f, loc=0, scale=1)
1.0000000000000011

>>> stats.norm.expect(f, loc=0, scale=np.sqrt(2))
1.9999999999999996
```

`scipy.integrate.quad` also has some predefined weight functions, although they are not normalized to be probability density functions.

The approximation error depends on the settings for the call to `integrate.quad`.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of brevity, 3 ways were suggested for calculating the expected value of f(x) under the probability p(x):

- Assuming p is given in closed-form, use `scipy.integrate.quad` to evaluate `f(x)p(x)`
- Assuming p can be sampled from, sample N values `x=P(N)`, then evaluate the expected value by `np.mean(f(X))` and the error by `np.std(f(X))/np.sqrt(N)`
- Assuming p is available at `stats.norm`, use `stats.norm.expect(f)`
- Assuming we have the `CDF(x)` of the distribution rather than `p(x)`, calculate `H=Inverse[CDF]` and then integrate `f(H(x))` using `scipy.integrate.quad`

Answer (score 0):

Another possibilty would be to integrate x -> f( H(x)) where H is the inverse of the cumulative distribution of your probability distribtion.

[This is because of change of variable: replacing y=CDF(x) and noting that p(x)=CDF'(x) yields the change dy=p(x)dx and thus int{f(x)p(x)dx}==int{f(x)dy}==int{f(H(y))dy with H the inverse of CDF.]